# JSDoc - defining detailed return type for array of predefined types

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

TLDR; how can I translate:

```
/** @return {((function(...[*]=))|{})[]} */
```

into its own `@typedef`.

---

I'm trying to properly define the value returned from my function within a `@typedef` using JSDoc and I can not get it correctly defined without replacing my type with `@return {((function(...[*]=))|{})[]} *`.

What I currently have:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Array} MyType
 * @property {function(): void} submit - Submit
 * @property {Object} state - FetchResult
 */

/** @return {MyType} */
function fooBar() {
    return [() => {}, {}];
}
```

results in the warning:

```
Returned expression type ((function(...[*]=)) | {})[] is not assignable to type MyType
```

Replacing the JSDoc for `fooBar()` with:

```
/** @return {((function(...[*]=))|{})[]} */
```

results in the correct behaviour.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is document properties on the Array type itself, not the values that are within the array:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Array} MyType
 * @property {function(): void} submit - Submit <--- MyType.submit?
 * @property {Object} state - FetchResult       <--- MyType.state?
 */
```

What you *may* want to do is a named label for the array index:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Array} MyType
 * @property {Function} 0 - Submit function
 * @property {Object} 1 - state
 */
```

However, [judging by this currently-open issue for jsdocs](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1073) I would say that this doesn't fully solve the problem. The return expression within `fooBar` will still probably be highlighted, saying that `"*[] is not assignable to type MyType"` even if you have `@returns {MyType}` documenting the function.